# Time counter for sending data

Tags: javascript, c, timer

I am trying to find the total time between data being sent and received. I am simply sending some random generated data from a C-program via [websocket](http://websocketd.com/), and the data is received in JavaScrip that displays a nice diagram using [Canvas.js](http://canvasjs.com/editor/?id=http://canvasjs.com/example/gallery/dynamic/realtime_line/).

How can I find the total time, could I write a simple C-code or JavaScript code, or is there any program that handles this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with Javascript. If you just want to see the time in your console, use `console.time`.

```js
console.time("answer time");
alert("Click to continue");
console.timeEnd("answer time");
```

Move `console.timeEnd` in your callback ajax, and `console.time` before your ajax call.

---

*Reference*

- [Console MDN Timers](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/console#Timers)